# Kendo UI Scheduler error "this.intlService.weekendRange is not a function"

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-scheduler

I recently updated my scheduler to version 1.0.1 and I got this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.intlService.weekendRange is not a function
   at SchedulerComponent.get [as workWeek] (index.js:2536)
   at SchedulerComponent.push../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-scheduler/dist/fesm5/index.js.SchedulerComponent.notifyOptionsChange (index.js:2495)
   at SchedulerComponent.push../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-scheduler/dist/fesm5/index.js.SchedulerComponent.ngAfterContentInit (index.js:2243)
   at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:22409)
   at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:22390)
   at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:22380)
   at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23311)
   at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
   at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23511)
   at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23308)
```

The HTML hasn't changed so I suspect the update broke it.  Even with the below the error is occuring on the line `<kendo-scheduler>`

```
<kendo-scheduler>
    <kendo-scheduler-month-view>
    </kendo-scheduler-month-view>
</kendo-scheduler>
```

The scheduler month seems to be the only view that works (day, week all appear incorrectly as 1 line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I looked at the npm update I got warnings like:

```
npm WARN @progress/kendo-angular-scheduler@1.0.1 requires a peer of @progress/kendo-angular-buttons@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @progress/kendo-angular-scheduler@1.0.1 requires a peer of @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @progress/kendo-angular-scheduler@1.0.1 requires a peer of @progress/kendo-angular-dialog@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @progress/kendo-angular-scheduler@1.0.1 requires a peer of @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @progress/kendo-angular-scheduler@1.0.1 requires a peer of @progress/kendo-angular-popup@^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @progress/kendo-angular-scheduler@1.0.1 requires a peer of @progress/kendo-angular-intl@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @progress/kendo-angular-scheduler@1.0.1 requires a peer of @progress/kendo-angular-l10n@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @progress/kendo-angular-scheduler@1.0.1 requires a peer of @progress/kendo-recurrence@^1.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Once I resolved these I no longer got the error.

Comment: worked for me too, thanks. Usual package version issues. Such waste of time.